# Ionic not showing photo from gallery after selection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to get a photo from the gallery to be displayed on my screen, the page I am working on is a tab page, using the following code I can open the photo gallery and select the image, however, the image never gets displayed on the screen unless I switch tabs, any idea on how to fix this will be much appreciated.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraResultType, CameraSource } from '@capacitor/camera';

@Component({
selector: 'app-sign-reader',
templateUrl: './sign-reader.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./sign-reader.page.scss']
})


export class SignReaderPage {
    myImage = null;

  constructor() {}

  async takePicture() {
   const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 90,
  allowEditing: false,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
  source: CameraSource.Photos
    });

this.myImage = image.webPath;
  }

}
```

here is the HTML code:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-title>
    Capacitor PWA
  </ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-button (click)="takePicture()" expand="block">
  <ion-icon name="camera" slot="start"></ion-icon>
  Capture image
   </ion-button>

  <ion-img *ngIf="myImage" [src]="myImage"></ion-img>
 </ion-content>
```

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)    Ionic Framework
> : @ionic/angular 5.6.7    @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
> @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8    @angular/cli
> : 10.0.8    @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI      : 3.0.0    @capacitor/android : 3.0.0
> @capacitor/core    : 3.0.0    @capacitor/ios     : 3.0.0
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res                          : not installed globally
> native-run (update available: 1.4.0) : 1.3.0
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v14.15.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)    npm    : 6.14.10    OS
> : macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

Remember having a similar issue. Using Base64 instead of URI solved it for me.

Comment: async takePicture() {
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: false,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      source: CameraSource.Photos
    }).then(res=>{  
  alert(res.base64String);
  this.myImage =  'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + res.base64String;
 });

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine on my app on capacitor 2. Probably you can try using changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after the image is loaded. This forces the app to detect changes and you will not need to refresh the page manually.